# How do I have save a list of shapely.Polygon objects as one geojson file?

Tags: python, geojson, shapely

Pretty straight forward question.

I have a list of shapely polygons in my python script. I want to save this list as one geojson object. I tried looping through the list and saving each one but that just saves them as individual geojson files (obviosuly). Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?